# Typedefs, Ruby and SWIG

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I'm trying to generate a Ruby wrapper for some C++ classes. The generation succeeds, all methods are created, but the problem is that a lof of the C++ methods use this:

```
#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
typedef unsigned long long Count;   /* a count of something */
#else
typedef unsigned long Count;        /* a count of something */
#endif
```

When I run a method inside irb which returns a Count, I get something like this:

```
irb(main):006:0> ngram.numNgrams(0)
=> #<SWIG::TYPE_p_Count:0x00000001c52280>
```

I expected a number... I tried using reflection to see if I can get the value somehow, but no cigar. Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typedef is preventing SWIG from determining that `Counter` is an unboxed type that it can convert directly. Without additional information, it's treating `Counter` as an abstract object type that can only be produced and consumed by functions in the library.

You need to tell SWIG that `Counter` is equivalent to intrinsic `long` or `long long`.

The `typemap` is SWIG's way of doing this. Additionally the SWIG language itself provides `typedef`s to state the equivalence of `Counter` and its underlying intrinsic type.

Here's how it works. You should be able to transform this easily to a solution to your problem:

```
// hacking.i
%module hacking
%{
// "Simulation" of the header included verbatim in the glue code.
#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
typedef unsigned long long Count;   /* a count of something */
#else
typedef unsigned long Count;        /* a count of something */
#endif
Count foo(Count count) { return count; }
%}

// The typemaps...
%typemap(in) Count n {
#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
 $1 = ULL2INT($input);
#else
 $1 = ULONG2INT($input);
#endif
}

%typemap(out) Count {
#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
 $result = ULL2NUM($1);
#else
 $result = ULONG2NUM($1);
#endif
}

// Now tell SWIG about the type equivalences and function prototype.
#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
typedef unsigned long long Count;   /* a count of something */
#else
typedef unsigned long Count;        /* a count of something */
#endif
Count foo(Count count);
```

Note that if `USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS` is defined, the Ruby you are using must support the `long long` type. Not all do.

Typemaps are powerful, with lots of options. You didn't provide enough information to give a more specific solution to your problem. Citing the [Ruby SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html) is about all that's possible until you furnish more.

Now to build, make a file:

```
# extconf.rb
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('hacking')
```

And (omit `-DUSE_LONGLONGCOUNTS` if you need `unsigned long` instead):

```
$ swig -c++ -DUSE_LONGLONG_COUNTS -ruby -o wrap.cpp hacking.i
$ ruby extconf.rb
$ make
compiling wrap.cpp
linking shared-object hacking.bundle
$ make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 hacking.bundle ...  
$ irb
2.2.1 :001 > require 'hacking'
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > Hacking.foo(1234567890123454567)
 => 1234567890123454567
```

Answer (score 1):

This is strange.

Are you sure that swig is "seeing" your `typedef` of `Count`? Since otherwise `Count` is just some type that swig knows nothing about, and it will wrap it as a pointer to the C object, in which case swig should generate a warning.

Anyway, I just created an example from your question and tested it as is with swig 3.0.7 and for me it just works as expected (without typemaps):

dummy.i (comment `#define USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS` for the other case)

```
%module dummy

%inline %{

#define USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS

#ifdef USE_LONGLONG_COUNTS
typedef unsigned long long Count;   /* a count of something */
#else
typedef unsigned long Count;        /* a count of something */
#endif

Count returnCount(Count count) { return count; }

%}
```

extconf.rb

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('dummy')
```

To compile and run ruby, I do:

```
swig -c++ -ruby dummy.i
ruby extconf.rb
make
irb
```

Then in `irb`, I can do:

```
irb(main):001:0> require_relative 'dummy'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Dummy.returnCount(2**64-1)
=> 18446744073709551615
irb(main):003:0> Dummy.returnCount(-1)
=> 18446744073709551615
irb(main):004:0> Dummy.returnCount(2**64)
TypeError: Expected argument 0 of type Count, but got Bignum 18446744073709551616
in SWIG method 'returnCount'
from (irb):4:in `returnCount'
from (irb):4
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Note that both `unsigned long long` and `unsigned long` are 64 bit on my system / compiler, and these are supported by my version of ruby. Perhaps the conversions may not work if this were not true, I don't know.

In any case, it is not the `typedef` that is causing the problem, as claimed in another answer.